# How To Synchronise the Android SqLite Db With Oracle Lite DB

Tags: android, database, synchronization

I would like to know how to Synchronise the Android SqLite Db With Oracle Lite DB..

I need the complete requirements and installation documentation to achieve this issue..

Do reply as soon as possible..

Thanks & Regards,
Gowtham.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no doc I am aware of that will migrate your database from the Oracle Lite DB to SQLite DB. Perhaps the next release of the Oracle Mobile Server will have something more concrete.

You could perhaps sync the Oracle Lite DB to the mobile server, deploy your solution on an android device and then sync again with the same user on the android device. I have not tried this, so I do not know the short comings about this approach.